# Cant save webp format with imagick

Tags: php, jpeg, imagick, webp

Im developing a panel in which Im uploading a jpg, it copies it, resizes it, saves another jpg and now I want also to be able to create a copy but using webp extension.

Ive checked everywhere and couldnt find anyone with the same problem.
Im running cPanel on CentOS
cPanel > Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01

```
$imagick = new \Imagick($targetJpg); 
$imagick->writeImage('webp:'.$targetWebp);
```

**I was getting this error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: delegate failed `'cwebp'
>   -quiet %Q '%i' -o '%o'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1928 in /...dirs.../pic-upload.php:108 Stack trace: #0
>   /...dirs.../pic-upload.php(108):
>   Imagick->writeimage('webp:../images/...') #1

=========================================================

In my local machine, OSX, using Mamp, that was solved with @MarkSetchell help.

On OSX > Terminal
type: cwebp -version
webp 1.1.0

type: type cwebp
cwebp is hashed (/usr/local/bin/cwebp)

Marks **solution** > Worked!  :)
On macOS, your cwebp seems to be the homebrew one in /usr/local/bin, so I would suggest you find your Imagick config file called delegates.xml and edit it so that where it says 'cwebp' -quiet -q %Q '%I'... it becomes '/usr/local/bin/cwebp' -quiet -q...

=========================================================

In CentOS cPanel

Neither cwebp or dwebp was installed. This was due to the package libwebp-tools not being installed.

I installed them and checked - results:
[root@server:/]$ whereis cwebp
cwebp: /usr/bin/cwebp /usr/share/man/man1/cwebp.1.gz
[root@server:/]$ whereis dwebp
dwebp: /usr/bin/dwebp /usr/share/man/man1/dwebp.1.gz

**Everything working now!**
Hope this is useful for someone else.
Thanks for the Mark and Chris for the help

Comment: What version of Imagick do you have?

Comment: Have you got `webp` installed on your Mac with `brew install webp`? Please also paste output of `cwebp -version` and `type cwebp`

Comment: @ChrisHaas in cPanel> Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01

Comment: @MarkSetchell $ cwebp -version 1.1.0 $ cwebp Usage: cwebp [options] -q quality input.png -o output.webp where quality is between 0 (poor) to 100 (very good). Typical value is around 80. Try -longhelp for an exhaustive list of advanced options.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your answer and include the output from `type cwebp` and also the output from `identify -list delegate`

Comment: I don't understand why you have mixed up macOS and CentOS stuff in the same question, but I think PHP Imagick is unable to find your `cwebp` program. On macOS at least, your `cwebp` seems to be the **homebrew** one in `/usr/local/bin`, so I would suggest you find your Imagick config file called `delegates.xml` and edit it so that where it says `'cwebp' -quiet -q %Q '%I'...` it becomes `'/usr/local/bin/cwebp' -quiet -q...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I need to solve the issue in CentOS and OSX because Im developing a website, that I need to test and be able to run on my computer, using mamp, and also need to be able to upload it to my server, using cPanel and centos. - Your answer solved the OSX and mamp issue. Thanks!